# How "Session_Start" in Global.Asax works ?. MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables, global-asax

I'am trying uderstand how "Session_Start" in Global.Asax works. Let's say I've got few pages on my website. For example: I'am entering on "Page A", then function "Session_Start" is firing. Then I'am going to "Page B", and what than ?. Function will firing again, or not ?. I'am trying to write code which will check that cookie "User" exist, and if exist, code will return Session["userName"] variable, but I'am not sure is "Session_Start" good place for that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make session unlimited, you can use cookies.
Which I think you are using, you mentioned that in your original query.

Session_End is fired when user logs out, closes browser to end the session or session times out.

You can keep the cookie on user's browser. And check the cookie in Session_Start for valid values. And resume the session for the user.

You can also increase the session timeout from server configuration.

Comment: Thank You very much. I'am trying to avoid the situation when someone will log on, then leave computer for 25minutes, come back and he will have to log on once again, because Session["userName"} expired :/. Thats why I asked about this "Session_Start" function on the beginning. Probably I'am wrong, but i think the easiest way to avoid this is put somewhere in global asax file code which will check that cookie exist and returning new Session any time, across all pages.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not fire again, for second page.
Session_Start fires the first time when a user's session is started

You can use this to check user cookie and save the result to session variable to access in further pages.

Comment: Thank You for answer !. Than one more qustion: Session variable has expired time. Is there option to set expired time for this session to "Unlimited" or something like this ?. And if someone will close the browser, how remove this single session ?. Can I do that in "Session_End" ?