# How does ASP.NET know to create the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie if Session_Start is defined?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies

I've done quite a bit of testing on this, and I'm thoroughly confused. It seems ASP.NET will generate an `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie if the `Session_Start` method in the `MvcApplication` class is defined, even if I'm not using the `Session` variable anywhere. That seems odd, considering there doesn't have to be anything in the method's body.

Example (Global.asax.cs):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        private void Session_Start() { } // this is all it takes to generate a SessionId (?)
    }
}
```

Now, I'm confused for multiple reasons:

1. How is the mere presence of the `Session_Start` function enough to generate a SessionId? I'm not utilizing the `Session` variable anywhere in the application, and the method is empty.
2. The `Session_Start` method is private, and I'm obviously not calling it anywhere inside the class, so how does ASP.NET know when a session starts?
3. How does anything outside of this class even know the `Session_Start` method exists, and to check for a SessionId cookie? It isn't a partial class, and it's explicitly marked `private`.

I know these reasons sort of blend into one another, but I'm really at a loss as to how this works.

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445912/how-session-start-in-global-asax-works-mvc

Comment: or

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

Comment: I don't always put `Session_Start` in my Application class, and I still get SessionID's. I think the answer you seek is elsewhere.

Comment: @mason - I only get SessionIds when I define that method. If I comment it out, I no longer get a SessionId cookie, so it's definitely `Session_Start`.

Comment: @johnnyRose What if you comment that out, but use the Session object on some web form or controller?

Comment: @mason - I assume it would still generate a SessionId. I edited my question to be slightly clearer, since that was really never my question to begin with.

Comment: @johnnyRose My point was that it appears the framework intelligently adds the SessionID if it's needed. Even though Session_Start may be marked as private, the framework could be using reflection to check for its presence. If you really want to know the answer, I suggest you search the [ASP.NET source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/). If i had to venture a guess, the answer is somewhere within the `System.Web.SessionState` namespace. Probably try to figure out what calls [CreateSessionID](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/R/e870575572388e1c.html).

Comment: It's a lot easier to know whether a `Session_Start` exists or not than it is to know whether it does anything or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Session_Start` is like an event handler for the application.  When a new session is created, this method is called by the application.  It does not create Session IDs, it is meant as a way for the developer to know when a user visits the site for the first time (that session).  This can be used to run some initialization routines or tracking purposes (e.g., we had x number of unique sessions today).

What triggers the creation of the Session and SessionID is a user visiting a page that has session enabled-- ASP.NET will create the Session behind the scenes.  The answer to this question has two ways of enabling session state for pages: [Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true either in a configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334147/session-state-can-only-be-used-when-enablesessionstate-is-set-to-true-either-in)

In summary:

in web.config, for all pages:

```
<system.web>
      <pages enableSessionState="true" /> 
 </system.web>
```

in your page.aspx, on a per-page basis (set it to false to turn it off on a per-page basis):

```
<%@Page enableSessionState="true">
```

Your web.config should also configure the SessionState mode. This is an example of using the server's memory to store session state:

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your (very good) answer. I know the `Session_Start` method doesn't actually create the SessionIds, but I guess I'm still confused as to how the mere presence of the private method tells ASP.NET to generate those Ids. Does that make sense?

Comment: It doesn't.  What happens if you remove that method?  I don't believe any of the Application Events have to be implemented.

Comment: I'm not using the session variable anywhere else in my application, so when I remove it, SessionIds are no longer created - which makes sense when you say it. I just don't understand *how*.

Comment: hmm, so maybe that's simply another trigger.  If you disable session state on all your pages, would the `Session_Start` method still be hit?  In the example above, set `<pages enableSessionState="false" />` in the web.config and see what happens.

Comment: Same behavior - a SessionId cookie is created when `Session_Start` is defined.